# If i don't know the exact sizes of all the component in the FlatList would getitemlayour be useful for the ones that I know?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I want to optimize the scrolling of the Flatlist so it does not jump as much. I have a relatively random set of items but some items I can predict the exact height. But obviously not offset

Can getitemlayour still be used or it has to be avoided because of the items I am not able to compute for.

I tried to use it but I get A lot of blank and inactive areas. Not sure if i  am using it correctly though.

Comment: `getItemLayout` is efficient if you have fixed size items, React Native documentation describe it that way. So I think it'll not be efficient if height or width aren't known beforehand. check the documentation https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#getitemlayout

Answer (score 0):

No, `getItemLayout` only works if you know all the dimensions and offsets of each item. This allows the FlatList to create the native views for each item before they appear on the screen. You're seeing the native views at the size and offset you're setting in `getItemLayout`.

If you can't change the design of the component to be predictably sized, there are other ways to optimize FlatLists, but this way will not work for you.